# Nextjs App Router Server Action confirm auth with supabase

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to make a landing page for when an user confirms his account by the link from the confirmation email. The link is redirecting him to /confirm?code=XXXXXXX where the server action should log in him in exhange for the code. The thing is: it doesn't work. I don't really know why, I don't receive any error and the log for the testing is displaying.

```
import {cookies} from "next/headers";
import {createClient} from "@/utilities/supabase/server";

import Redirect from "@/utilities/redirect/redirect";

import styles from "./page.module.scss";

async function confirm(code: string) {
    "use server";

    if (code) {
        const cookieStore = cookies();
        const supabase = createClient(cookieStore);
        try {
            const {error} = await supabase.auth.exchangeCodeForSession(code);
            console.log(code);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}

export default async function Confirmare({
    searchParams,
}: {
    searchParams: {code: string};
}) {
    const cookieStore = cookies();
    const supabase = createClient(cookieStore);
    const code = searchParams.code;

    const {
        data: {user},
    } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

    let logged: boolean = false;

    if (user && user.role == "authenticated") {
        logged = true;
    }

    if (!logged) {
        await confirm(code);
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.confirmPage}>
            {!logged ? (
                <>
                    <h2>Contul tău a fost confirmat cu succes.</h2>
                    <h3>Vei fi redirecționat către pagina de autentificare.</h3>
                </>
            ) : (
                <Redirect logged={logged} source="confirmare" path="/" />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```